# test GPS without service provider

Tags: ios

While I found a question asked for android (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189188/gps-location-without-service) I couldn't find one for iOS so I thought I'd ask it. Especially since it seems to be possible in Android (see link).

I'm wondering if there's anyway to get location without a service provider.  For example, I have access to an older iPhone 3GS but clearly don't want to pay any fees just to test my location services code.

I'm thinking that since location should be determinable via WIFI then maybe the only difference would be the increased precision of GPS.  Maybe that'll be enough.

Comment: Have you considered using the simulator?

Comment: Yes but at some point I'll need to test on a device.

Comment: Yes, but if you just want to see if the logic of your code is correct, the simulator will work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got the answer by posting at Apple's devforums.

Basically, Location Services are independent of GPS - the APIs are identical regardless of device.

Which makes sense.  Essentially, the only difference with actual GPS-based location is precision.

Answer (score 0):

What fees are you worried about ? If it's mobile data charges then just switch off mobile data - the gps will still work fine!

Comment: Although its good to know that the GPS will work, it's not the mobile data charges, it's any charges (i.e. the monthly services charges).  Soon enough there'll be pre-paid iPhones which may, at the very least, reduce the cost.

Comment: I have a pay-as-you-go iPhone and so do loads of other people. If I don't make any calls and don't use any mobile data, it's free. What country are you in? Can't you get a PAYG Sim and pop it into your phone?

Comment: Actually, forgot to mention, with T-mobile in the UK you can get a PAYG (pre paid) SIM for £10 and get 12 months of free internet access. So my mobile data is currently free too.